# Add a mosaic to a cached service and update the cache maintaining the existing cache tiles

Tags: arcgis-server, cache

Is there any way to add a mosaic to a cached service, and update the cache of this service maintaining the existing cache tiles

I have the following scenario in my work, 
I add images (1,2,3) to a mosaic data set(A) then I added  the mosaic (A) to an MXD then I publish and Cache the service using ArcGIS server 10.3.1.
Now I got new Images ( 4,5,6) and added them to mosaic (B) and I need to add them to the same MXD and use publish overwrite the service.

But the question here is there any method to avoid starting the cache form the scratch? Since the mosaic (A) was already cached before, and now I only need the new mosaic (B) to be cached to save the time and space, while both A and B lives in the same service

Comment: anytime you make adjustments to the cache data in an MXD you will be required to update the cache (rebuild). The only workaround would be if you have the [Image Server Extension](http://www.esri.com/software/arcgis/arcgisserver/extensions/image-extension) and created a [Mosaic Dataset](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/manage-data/raster-and-images/creating-a-mosaic-dataset.htm) to allow for On-the-fly processing (aka Dynamic Mosaicking)

Comment: Do you mean that I I published the mosaic as an Image service I will be able to update the cache without starting form the scratch